# Ошибка Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 в eclips

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Здравствуйте. Помогите решить ошибку Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 в eclips, из за которой нельзя запустить проект на мобильном устройстве.
Очень прошу помочь!

[image: Скрин ошибки. Очень прошу помочь!]

[![Скрин ошибки. Очень прошу помочь!][3]][3]

Comment: Ваш проект содержит ошибку(ошибки), пожалуйста пофиксите их прежде чем стартовать ваше  приложение.

Comment: Приведите список используемых библиотек. Скорее всего одна из них несовместима по байт-коду с Dalvik.

Comment: Видимых ошибок на которые бы eclipse показывал нет.

Comment: А в папках `libs` есть еще что?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Dalvik можно сконвертировать только байткод Java 6, если целевое устройство с KitKat (API19) и выше, то и байткод Java 7.
Поддержка байткода Java 8 еще не вышла в релиз.
Проверьте все библиотеки и настройки проека.